# Prisma migration cause data lose

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I'm new to prisma I'm working on a project with nodejs & prisma , my database isn't empty and I did some changes in prisma schema and I want to migrate it without data lose is there any solution please ?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more clarification on what problem you're facing and the exact circumstances? Furthermore, if it's a dev database you could just query the data and reseed the database.

Comment: No it's a production database hosted in a VPS and I want to add some columns but I don't want the data be lost

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MohamedFadelMoumeni I have answered based on the clarification you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Answered based on the problem you mentioned in the comment: ***"I want to add some columns but I don't want existing data be lost"***

if you want to add new columns to an existing database without causing data loss you need to make sure the new columns/field are optional. This can be done in Prisma by marking the type of the field with a `?`.

If you need the field to be mandatory, you could do it in three steps:

1. Create the new field as optional first in your prisma schema and run a migration
2. Run a script to update all records with that field to have certain data (what that data should depend on your context). This will have to be done for the production database data as well.
3. Mark the field is as mandatory in your Prisma schema and run a migration. It will not cause data loss now because the field is `non-null` for all records in the database.